# sql cross table calculations

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Hi i need to write a query that does multiple things, i made it so it can get the details of orders from within a certain time frame as well as for ages between 20 and 30, however i need to check if the orders product cost more then a set amount

however that data is in multiple tables

one table has the orderid the prodcode and quantity, while the other day has the prod information such as code and price, and im 3rd from another table

So i need to access the price of the product with the prodcode and quantity to do a cross table calculation and see if its above 100 and trying to do this with an and where command

so if i have 3 tables

Orderplaced table with oid odate custno paid

ordered table with oid itemid quant

items itemid itemname price

and i need to do a calcultion across those tabkes in my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Orderplaced.OID, Orderplaced.odate, Orderplaced.custno, Orderplaced.paid
FROM Cust, Orderplaced, items, Ordered
WHERE Orderplaced.odate BETWEEN '01-JUL-14' AND '31-DEC-14'
AND Floor((sysdate-Cust.DOB) / 365.25) Between '20' AND '30'
AND Cust.SEX='M'
AND items.itemid=ordered.itemid
AND $sum(ordered.quan*item.PRICE) >100;
```

no matter what way i try to get the calculation to work it doesnt seem to work always returns the same result even on orders under 100 dollars

so any advice on this would be good as its for my studies but is troubling me a lot

Comment: You have four tables and one join condition.  Fix the `from` clause, preferably using explicit joins.  A simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: What's $sum doing? Can you see the value if you put this calculation in SELECT?

Comment: As Gordon said. You are missing some joins. You don't have a join between Cust and OrderPlaced. You don't have a join between OrderPlaced and Ordered, and I'm not sure what $sum() is returning. The reason you're getting back all the orders is because the query is returning every combination of cust, orderplaced, and ordered

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. (I not familiar with $sum, I've replaced it with SUM())

```
SELECT 
  Orderplaced.OID,
  Orderplaced.odate,
  Orderplaced.custno,
  Orderplaced.paid,
  sum(ordered.quan * item.PRICE)
FROM
  Cust 
  JOIN Orderplaced ON Cust.CustNo = Orderplaced.custno
  JOIN Ordered ON Ordered.Oid = Orderplaced.Oid
  JOIN items ON items.itemid = ordered.itemid
WHERE
  Orderplaced.odate BETWEEN date 2014-07-01  AND date 2014-12-31
  AND Floor((sysdate-Cust.DOB) / 365.25) Between 20 AND 30
  AND Cust.SEX = 'M'
GROUP BY
  Orderplaced.OID,
  Orderplaced.odate,
  Orderplaced.custno,
  Orderplaced.paid  
HAVING  
  sum(ordered.quant * item.PRICE) > 100;
```

Comment: It's generally a good idea to use the correct types for dates and numbers.  Because '`200'` is a string which falls between `'20'` and `'30'`.

Comment: Thanks @APC. You're right. And thanks for correctly placing the Group By clause.

Comment: You're welcome.  Also the DISTINCT is now redundant, because the GROUP BY will do that anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to try something like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT Orderplaced.OID, Orderplaced.odate, Orderplaced.custno, Orderplaced.paid
FROM Cust
JOIN Orderplaced ON
    Cust.<SOMEID> = OrderPlaces.<CustId>
AND Orderplaced.odate BETWEEN '01-JUL-14' AND '31-DEC-14'
 WHERE Floor((sysdate-Cust.DOB) / 365.25) Between 20 AND 30
AND Cust.SEX='M'
AND (
SELECT SUM(Ordered.quan*Item.PRICE)
FROM Ordered
    JOIN Item ON Item.ItemId = Ordered.ItemId
WHERE Ordered.<SomeId> = OrderPlaced.<SomeId>) > 100
```

Couple of pointers:
1. Floor returns a number... you are comparing it to a string
2. Typically, when referencing a table in a query, the table has to be joined on its primary keys, ie. In your query you're referencing Item and ordered, without joining any of those tables on any key columns.

Hope that helps